# Matlab plotting?

Tags: matlab, octave

This Matlab code here is supposed to plot the values stored in the vector X and Y which are already filled by the user, the problem here is : 
when you click on complex and real poles, the plotting results the right points, while when entering only real poles, the output is weird.
It's like the x-axis is on the y-axis, and I don't know what is exactly on the horizontal axis.

```
axis([-10,10,-10,10])
grid
[x,y] = ginput 

subplot(2,2,1)
axis([-10,10,-10,10])
grid

subplot(2,2,2)
axis([-10,10,-10,10])
hold all
grid


x = round (x)
y = round (y)

if( y > 0.5 | y < 0.5)
r1 = x + i*y
r2 = conj(r1)

plot (r1,'*')
hold all 
plot (r2,'*')

else

plot (x,y)

end
```

Comment: I've read through this a few times and I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: idk what you're trying to do here, but you realize that 'if( y > 0.5 | y < 0.5)' is only false for y=0.5, right?

Comment: Posting pictures of your plots would help a lot.

Comment: to add to jerad's comment `y = 0.5` will never occur because you `round` off the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @slayton : sorry for the misunderstanding, I hope I have made it clearer in my answer below.

Comment: @jerad : exaclty this was the mistake.

Comment: @mythealias : Hopefully next time I have a problem I'll post pictures.
Sorry I'm still new here and new to Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are saying, but I believe you problem is in the if statement as shown below. Specifically, you can never enter the first clause unless y=.5, which is unlikely. I suspect you wanted `abs(y)<0.5`, to look between [-0.5 0.5]. Secondly, your two plots don't match each other, the first plots complex numbers, and the second x and y values. That just doesn't seem right, but I'm not certain what you are trying to do, so I don't know how to fix it.

```
if( y > 0.5 | y < 0.5)

    r1 = x + i*y
    r2 = conj(r1)

    plot (r1,'*')
    hold all 
    plot (r2,'*')

else

    plot (x,y)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Y should be in this range : 
`if ( y > 0.5 | y < -0.5 )` 
I by mistake wrote it : `if ( y > 0.5 | y < 0.5 )`

and why I want this range, because I have the Y-axis representing the Imaginary axis, and the X-axis representing the Real axis, whenever I attempt to enter a Real number, the y coordinate always has a value for example y = 0.001, meaning it's never equal to zero, that's why I needed this approximation to assure that if Y's value is larger than 0.5 or smaller than -0.5 then it's a complex number, otherwise it's real.

And finally, I used : `scatter (x,y,'filled')` instead of plot cause plot drew a line, not points.

thanks for everyone :)